# How to stop Tasks firing during Django Nose tests?

Tags: python, django, django-nose

I have a testing which I use Django Nose. During a model creation I have a Celery task which is fired.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   celery_app.send_task('test.apps.action',
                                 args=["BB",
                                       self.user.id,
                                       ], kwargs={})
```

However when I run my tests I don't want it to run the Celery task! How can I do something like....

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

   if running_not_nose_tests:

       celery_app.send_task('test.apps.action')
   else:
       pass
```

So that tests don't run the tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it half way there :) For tests, I usually just a global variable (settings parameter in Django case). or environment variable telling one should skip certain aspects of the application under the test. This only if there is no other way to community with the underlying code, like settings class variables or flags.

In settings - create a separate settings file for running the tests:

```
SKIP_TASKS = True
```

Then:

```
from django.conf import settings

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

   if not settings.SKIP_TASKS:

       celery_app.send_task('test.apps.action')
   else:
       pass
```

Or from command line with environment variables:

```
SKIP_TASKS=true python manage.py test

import os

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

   if not os.environ.get("SKIP_TASKS"):

       celery_app.send_task('test.apps.action')
   else:
       pass
```

Comment: This would give me problems in my staging environment. Is there not a way to determine if the test runner is... running?

Comment: Use a different command line, environment variable or setting to determine if you are running the code in staging or not. The way to signal if the test runner is running is to tell it to the application when you start the tests "ok I am doing the test run now"

Comment: I see, could I pass in a system arg during the run test command ``python manage.py test --SKIP_TASKS =True``

Comment: @OrbiterFleet: But because it is Django, most people do this by passing in a different settings file for `python manage.py test`. Also you want environment variable (read my answer above), not command line argument.

Comment: Example `test_settings.py` for Django https://github.com/miohtama/LibertyMusicStore/blob/master/tatianastore/test_settings.py